# Batch Script to Collect Network Information

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

In order to troubleshoot a slow performing network, i need to create a batch script to obtain certain information from a users computer in order to analyze the cause further.. Unfortunately i have no experience with batch scripts, i have messed around with it but haven't been able to make it work as intended..

Basically what i need is a batch script that can check if a folder is already existing on the C:\ drive, if it doesn't already exist it needs to create the folder, if it does, it needs to collect the output of an ipconfig /all and a ping 8.8.8.8 and save it in the folder with the name ipconfig .txt and ping .txt so that the script doesn't overwrite previous saved files everytime they run it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
MD c:\folder
:Loop
Echo %Date% %Time% >> c:\folder\log.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 >> c:\folder\log.txt
ipconfig /all >> c:\folder\log.txt
Goto Loop
```

You don't need to check the folder. Just create it. If it already exists nothing will happen.